# How to write e-mail in footnote

Tags: footnotes

I have used `\ead{B.blah@gmail.com}` to see my email in the footnote. It works but the problems is that I want to write my name in front of the email in short form like (B.Blah) but it is written in the long form as (Blah Blah). What should I do?
A part of my code is

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{title}
\author{First authur} 
\ead{email1@gmail.com}
\author{Second Author\corref{cor1}} 
\ead{email2@gmail.com}
\address{address}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author:}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please share with us small but complete document which reproduce your problem (show what you try so far). For the clickable email address is usually use `hyperref` package. For example as `\href{mailto:name@name.com}{e-mail}`.

Comment: Where or how is the macro `\ead` defined?

Comment: I don't know how it is defined. I just enter the code above.

Comment: with this code I can see in the foor note something like this:  Email-adresses: email1@gmail.com (First Author) email2@gmail.com (Second Author) but I want to have this format : Email-adresses: email1@gmail.com (F.  Author) email2@gmail.com (S.  Author)

Comment: the document class is added.

Comment: `texdoc elsaarticle`?

Answer (score 5):

As @Zarko has already pointed out in a comment, the `\href` command (provided by the `hyperref` package) may be what you're looking for. E.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Hello.\footnote{\href{mailto:b.blah@gmail.com}{B. Blah}}
\end{document}
```

Clicking on the string "B. Blah" will open your default email Program, with an email message addressed to "b.blah@gmail.com".

Comment: No I don't want this. I explained it more clearly in the comments above.

Comment: @sarakaviani, than write this as ordinary text.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no provision in `elsarticle` for specifying different forms for authors' names.

Here's a hack.

```latex
\documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{title}
\author{First authur} 
\ead{email1@gmail.com}
\author{Second Author\corref{cor1}} 
\ead{email2@gmail.com}
\address{address}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author:}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what is difference with mine?